# Excel VBA: open fixed file path but not fixed file name

Tags: excel, vba, file, path

I want to write a code that will open the file path and within this folder the  user can select his own folder. I only seem able to find a  "**general" code to open a folder.**

```
With wbtarget.Sheets("Data")
    strPathName = Application.GetOpenFilename()      
    If strPathName = "False" Then
       Exit Sub
    End If        
    Set wbsource = Workbooks.Open(strPathName, 0)
    .Range("A1:AL10000").Value = wbsource.Sheets(1).Range("A1:AL10000").Value
    wbsource.Close (False)
End With
```

**or open a specific file.**

```
folder_path = CStr("C:\Users\peter\Documents\me")
file_name = CStr("report.xlsm")
StrResource = folder_path & "\" & file_name
```

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to let the user browse for a folder instead of a file. I don't remember where I found it.
It uses the [Shell.BrowseForFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774065%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method.

Set InitPath to a string <> "", e.g. "D:\Files", to limit the folder tree the user can choose from.

```
Public Function GetFolderName(Caption As String, InitPath As String) As String

    Dim AppShell As Object
    Dim BrowseDir As Variant
    Dim sPath As String

    Set AppShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    If InitPath <> "" Then
        Set BrowseDir = AppShell.BrowseForFolder(0, Caption, &H11, (InitPath))
    Else
        ' 17 = root folder is "My Computer"
        Set BrowseDir = AppShell.BrowseForFolder(0, Caption, &H11, 17)
    End If

    sPath = ""
    On Error Resume Next
    sPath = BrowseDir.Items().Item().Path
    GetFolderName = sPath

End Function
```